# How to write an inline big string in F#

Tags: .net, string, f#, literals

In C# I can use:

```
string myBigString = @"

<someXmlForInstance>
  <someChild />
</someXmlForInstance>

";
```

How to do this in F#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In F# 3.0, VS 2012, support was added for [triple-quoted strings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx).

> In a triple-quoted string, everything between triple-quotes ("""...""")
>   is kept verbatim; there is no escaping at all.  As a result, if I want
>   to have a bit of XAML as a string literal, it’s easy:

```
let xaml = """ 
<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            Name="mainPanel"> 
  <Border BorderThickness="15.0" BorderBrush="Black"> 
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1"> 
      <TextBlock Text="Super BreakAway!" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" /> 
      <TextBlock Text="written in F#, by Brian McNamara - press 'p' to pause" 
                 FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" /> 
      <Border BorderThickness="2.0" BorderBrush="Black"> 
        <Canvas Name="canvas" Background="White" /> 
      </Border> 
    </StackPanel> 
  </Border> 
</StackPanel>"""
```

Answer (score 2):

> If preceded by the @ symbol, the literal is a verbatim string. This means that any escape sequences are ignored, except that two quotation mark characters are interpreted as one quotation mark character.
>
> Source: [Strings (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323829.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try just :

```
let str1 = "abc
     def"
let str2 = "abc\
     def"
```

For more information see: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx